# Output is Displayed in console and not in the File

Tags: java

```
 try {
      BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/aravind/Desktop/India.txt"));

       ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> Location = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> Id = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> Details = new ArrayList<>();
       String line = " ";
       while ((line = sc.readLine()) != null) {

            if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("name")) {
                        name.add(line.split(":")[1].trim());
                    }
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("Location")) {
                        Location.add(line.split(":")[1].trim());
                    }
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("Id")) {
                        Id.add(line.split(":")[1].trim());
                    }
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("Details")) {
                        Details.add(line.split(":")[1].trim());
                    }
             }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(newFileWriter("output.csv"));

            out.println("name;Location;Id;Details;");

            out.println(name.get(i) + ";" 
               + Location.get(i) + ";" 
               + Id.get(i) + ";" 
               + Details.get(i) + ";");
            out.close();
        }
        sc.close();            
 } catch (Exception e) {

 }
```

and my input file looks like

> name = abc
>
> id = 123
>
> Place = xyz
>
> Details = some texts with two line
>
> name = aaa
>
> id = 54657
>
> Place = dfd
>
> Details = some texts with some lines

What could be the problem why it is not printing in csv file instead prints o/p in console..Kindly help me

Comment: Can you try to change your variable name for PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(newFileWriter("output.csv"));  to somethign else, so we can read it better

Comment: Does it throw an Exception (which you then silently ignore in your catch-block)? Put a `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch-block so you can see if something happens.

Comment: the separator in the file is "=" but you split on ":"

Comment: my seperator in another file is ":" so the code contains ";" rather "="

Comment: When you create a `PrintWriter` in a loop, you're going to constantly overwrite the first lines of the file.  Open the `PrintWriter` once, write to it as much as you need, and then close it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

In your file, title and value are always separated by "=", whereas at runtime you trim strings by ":". You should replace ":" by "=", thus your trim result will not be empty at index 1.:

```
name.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
```

Comment: if i run the if statement like this                                                                                              for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(newFileWriter("output.csv"));
             out.println("name;Location;Id;Details;");                                                                                     out.println(name.get(i))
            out.close();
            }                                                                              I am getting names column filled by names but id , place and details are emplty  rows

Comment: Of course, the actual writing happens in "out.println(name.get(i)));" . Do the same for the rest : "out.println(Id.get(i))"; But prefer putting it in an independent for loop because if name.size() is bigger than Id.size(), you will have IndexOutOfRange exception.

Comment: OH boy! Your lines are "name = blabla" whereas you trim by ":" symbol, so the 1 index of trim is empty!!